# Installed Eclipse 2020-06, but didn't get Maven Project under File->New Section

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have installed Eclipe 2020-06 but couldn't find  Maven Project option under File->New. So I tried creating a Maven Project from File->New->Project.

Then I got 2 warnings:

1. Build path specifies execution environment J2SE-1.5. There are no JREs installed in the workspace
   that are strictly compatible with this environment.new-project Build path JRE System
   Library Problem
2. The compiler compliance specified is 1.5 but a JRE 1.8 is used new-project Compiler
   Compliance JRE Compiler Compliance Problem

The content of pom.xml is attached as an image. It doesn't contain build or properties or dependencies blocks, which it should have contained.

[image: pom.xml and the warning is shown in the image]

I have JDK 1.8 and JRE 1.8 in Windows 7.

How to fix the problem? Should I install some other versions of Eclipse?

Comment: add maven compiler plugin for clean solution.

Comment: @emotionlessbananas not needed cause it's already bound within the life cycle... see the answer of J Fabian Meier  wich is the correct way.

Comment: @khmarbaise not sure about adding version in property, but adding plugin can also solve problem for nested child modules, if there's any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your Eclipse.

You just need to add

```
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>
```

to your `pom.xml`.

See also:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html

Comment: So have you updated your project with ALT+F5 or restarted your Eclipse?